# how to display dynamic array values to view from model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my model code:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $data = array(
                   'ptitle' =>$row->ptitle,
                    'technology' => $row->technology,
                    'description' => $row->description,

                    );

    $this->session->set_userdata('project',$data);
}
```

here is my View code:

```
<?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['project']))
{

     $ptitle = ($this->session->userdata['project']['ptitle']);
    $technology = ($this->session->userdata['project']['technology']);
    $description =  ($this->session->userdata['project']['description']);


}
?>
```

when i print array it displays

> Array ( [ptitle] => opmp [technology] => hbh [description] => kg ) Array ( [ptitle] => icicse [technology] => vv [description] => bhjv ) .can someone help me to print this values in view

Comment: add the above comment also in description.

Answer (score 0):

Setting session should be like this

```
$data = array(
    'ptitle'        => $row['ptitle'],
    'technology'    => $row['technology'],
    'description'   => $row['description'],
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

To retrive them use

```
if (isset($this->session->userdata['project']))
{

    $ptitle         = $this->session->userdata('ptitle');
    $technology     = $this->session->userdata('technology');
    $description    =  $this->session->userdata('description');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are storing multiple as array in `SESSION` then you surely need `foreach` in your view too.

Change from

```
if(isset($this->session->userdata['project']))
{
    $ptitle = ($this->session->userdata['project']['ptitle']);
    $technology = ($this->session->userdata['project']['technology']);
    $description =  ($this->session->userdata['project']['description']);
}
```

into

```
if(isset($this->session->userdata['project']))
{
    foreach($this->session->userdata['project'] as $project)
    {
        $ptitle = $project['ptitle'];
        $technology = $project['technology'];
        $description =  $project['description'];
        echo $ptitle.'<br>'.$technology.'<br>'.$description.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting only single array .i want multiple array to print in view

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your array like bellow and then pass it to session set data.

```
$project = array("project" =>
                         array(
                             'ptitle' => "ptitle",
                             'technology' => "technology",
                             'description' => "description",
                         )
                  );

$this->session->set_userdata($project);
```